# Checking if "Prefer External GPU" is enabled in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macos, macos-mojave

I'm making an application that should behave differently if ***"Prefer External GPU"*** is enabled or not.

> Explaining that quickly: in Mojave, now you can enable an option
>   called ***"Prefer External GPU"*** for any application in its ***"Get
>   info"*** window.

Although, I still couldn't find any method to retrieve that information.

- `NSBundle` didn't change since El Capitan, so it does not include any eGPU related info.
- `MTLDevice` didn't received any `isEnabled` function or similar, and none of its new Mojave methods seems to be helpful either.
- `MTLCopyAllDevices` *returns an array of references to all Metal devices in the system*, according to the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/1433367-mtlcopyalldevices?language=objc), so that includes the eGPUs, even the mentioned option is selected.
- `MTLCopyAllDevicesWithObserver` has the same problem, since in the [sample in the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/choosing_gpus_on_mac/device_selection_and_fallback_for_graphics_rendering#3010883), it returns *all Metal devices available to the system*, so that basically ignores the mentioned option again.
- The terminal command `mdls` doesn't seems to show any info related to eGPUs either (although I can be wrong, since I don't have any eGPU to check its output for an app if I enable the said option). Still, if it does exists, it's still undocumented:

> **Common Metadata Attribute Keys**
>   https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/file_metadata/mditem/common_metadata_attribute_keys?language=objc
>
> **File System Metadata Attribute Keys**
>   https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/file_metadata/mditem/file_system_metadata_attribute_keys?language=objc

Does anyone knows how to check that in Objective-C or using a terminal command? (I would prefer the first option, but in case there no other way I can run a terminal command within the app).

Comment: As of Big Sur (macOS 11.0), that option not longer exists on the "Get Info" window